# Jupyter bash mode with ssh connection

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
%%bash
ssh remote-machine
ls
exit
ls   <- does not execute
```

I want to ssh to some remote machine and do execute some bash commands there and then exit the ssh session and execute some bash commands on my local machine.

Comment: Can you do it in separate cells?

Comment: thought about it but was looking for something more neat! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it like so:

```
%%bash
ssh remote-machine <<EOF
echo ----------- remote -------------------
ls
hostname
echo ----------- remote -------------------
EOF

echo ----------- local -------------------
ls
hostname
echo ----------- local -------------------
```

None of this relies on anything special about the notebook or magic, it's all normal Bash stuff, and using the fact that `ssh` accepts an argument containing commands to execute on the remote machine.